# How to get current system time and cast in array?

Tags: c++, datetime, argument-passing

I want to get time and date separately to put it into an array.  I would like the calling function to be like `int date(int Day,int Month,int Year)` but it isnt correct.  How can I define arguments Year Month Day and Hour min sec of function to use them ?

```
using namespace std;
int date() {
    time_t currentTime;
    struct tm *localTime;

    time(&currentTime);                  
    localTime = localtime(&currentTime);

     int Day = localTime->tm_mday;
     int Month = localTime->tm_mon + 1;
     int Year = localTime->tm_year + 1900;
    return (0);
}
int time() {
    time_t currentTime;
    struct tm *localTime;

    time(&currentTime);                   
    localTime = localtime(&currentTime); 

    int Hour = localTime->tm_hour;
    int Min = localTime->tm_min;
    int Sec = localTime->tm_sec;
    return (0);
}
int main() {
    unsigned int new_date=date();
    char write[4];
    memcpy(write,&new_date,4);

    unsigned int new_time=time();
       char wrt[4];
       memcpy(wrt,&new_time,4);



    }
```

Comment: do you understand both `date()` and `time()` returns `0`?

Comment: yes i want to chang it but i dont know how??

Comment: Well, that is too broad, from current standpoint. First, pick a language. `C` and `C++` are not really the same.

Comment: Nothing to do with your issue, but if you want to `memcpy()` like that, you should use `sizeof(unsigned int)` instead of `4` if you want it to remain portable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare the function to pass arguments by reference:

```
              // pass arguments by reference to change them in the function 
int date(int &Day, int &Month, int&Year) {
    time_t currentTime;
    struct tm *localTime;

    time(&currentTime);                  
    localTime = localtime(&currentTime);

     Day = localTime->tm_mday;   // use the reference argument
     Month = localTime->tm_mon + 1;
     Year = localTime->tm_year + 1900;

    return (0);
}
```

You can then use it like this in `main()`:

```
int d,m,y; 
date(d,m,y); 
cout << d<<"/"<<m<<"/"<<y<<endl;
```

You can of course do the same thing for time.

Comment: with pleasure !  I'd recomment to make the function `void` instead of always returning 0 :  This would make clear that callers shall not expect anything from the returned value.